# Crop an Image to the shape of a Vector or Overlay a Shape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

I imagine this is a shot in the dark, but is it possible to have a vector file of a shape (in this case a hexagon with rounded corners), and pass an image through some code and have it coming out cropped in the shape of that vector?

I'm attempting to utilize hexagons in my design and have gone through every page I possibly can. I've seen the many HTML and CSS solutions, but none of them achieve what I'm looking for flawlessly.

Another idea I have is maybe overlaying a transparent hexagon shape with white corners on top of the existing image with imagemagick, and then going through and making any white transparent. Thoughts?

I don't have any code for cropping in the shape of a vector file, but here's what I have for overlaying an outline of the shape I want on top of the other picture:

```
imgfile = "public/" + SecureRandom.uuid + ".png"
SmartCropper.from_file(art.url(:original)).smart_square.resize(225,225).write(imgfile)

overlay = Magick::Image.read("app/assets/images/overlay.png")
img = Magick::Image.read(imgfile)         
img.composite(overlay,0,0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
```

Right now it's giving me an undefined method error for composite, which is strange because I've followed some other stack overflow questions using the same thing in their models.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes this is possible. Could you add your best attempt so far to the question, so any answer can start from where you've got to, and use same terminology? This saves time in writing an answer - even just cut&pasting variable names etc is a timesaver.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that. Added some code for adding an overlay.

Comment: Well I learned about SmartCropper - looks interesting. I assume "overlay.png" is your hexagon image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fallen for a common ImageMagick trap - the objects you get from the `.read` method are not `Magick::Image` objects but `Magick::ImageList` ones, and for most image types you want the first item from the list.

Without knowing how you have set up your **overlay.png** file, it is difficult to tell what the best composite option is. However, in a similar situation I found `CopyOpacityCompositeOp` to be useful, and to have the overlay's transparency control the transparency in the final image.

I tested the following code and it looks like it would do what you want if **overlay.png** was set up that way:

```
require 'smartcropper'

imgfile = "test_square.png"
SmartCropper.from_file( 'test_input.png' ).
    smart_square.resize( 225, 225 ).write( imgfile )

overlay = Magick::Image.read( 'overlay.png' ).first

img = Magick::Image.read( imgfile ).first

img.composite( overlay, 0, 0, Magick::CopyOpacityCompositeOp ).
    write( "test_result.png" )
```

Instead of reading `overlay` from a file, you could create it using `Magick::Draw` like this:

```
overlay = Magick::Image.new( 225, 225 ) do |i|
  i.background_color= "Transparent"
end

gc = Magick::Draw.new
gc.stroke('white').stroke_width(10)
gc.fill('white')
gc.polygon(97.5, 26.25, 178.5, 73.125, 178.5, 167, 
    97.5, 213.75, 16.5, 167, 16.5, 73.125)
gc.draw( overlay )
```

NB That's a hexagon, but I've not bothered centering it.

Comment: Worked absolutely perfectly! Thanks so much!